# Mac cocoapod and gem commands throwing error, Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoapods

I am trying to run "pod install" and "gem update" commands on my Mac. Actually, it is not just "pod install" or "gem update", any pod or gem commands. When I run the commands, I am getting the following error.

```
4: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `<main>'
3: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:22:in `eval'
2: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.6/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
1: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:284:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) with executable pod (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
waiyanhein@Mac-Mini-M1-Dev-HJ ios % sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
11: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
10: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:44:in `run'
 9: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `do_configuration'
 8: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `new'
 7: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
 6: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
 5: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:684:in `load_yaml'
 4: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 3: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 2: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
 1: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/psych.so (LoadError)
22: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
21: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:44:in `run'
20: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `do_configuration'
19: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `new'
18: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
17: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
16: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:684:in `load_yaml'
15: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
14: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
13: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
12: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
11: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
10: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:213:in `try_activate'
 9: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find_by_path'
 8: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find'
 7: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `each'
 6: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1037:in `block in find_by_path'
 5: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:39:in `compatible?'
 4: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
 3: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
 2: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:68:in `lockfile_version'
 1: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `lockfile_contents'
/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
waiyanhein@Mac-Mini-M1-Dev-HJ ios % sudo gem update
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
11: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
10: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:44:in `run'
 9: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `do_configuration'
 8: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `new'
 7: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
 6: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
 5: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:684:in `load_yaml'
 4: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 3: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 2: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
 1: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/psych.so (LoadError)
22: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
21: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:44:in `run'
20: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `do_configuration'
19: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `new'
18: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
17: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
16: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:684:in `load_yaml'
15: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
14: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
13: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
12: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
11: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
10: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:213:in `try_activate'
 9: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find_by_path'
 8: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find'
 7: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `each'
 6: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1037:in `block in find_by_path'
 5: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:39:in `compatible?'
 4: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
 3: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
 2: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:68:in `lockfile_version'
 1: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `lockfile_contents'
/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
waiyanhein@Mac-Mini-M1-Dev-HJ ios % sudo gem update
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/gem-wrappers-1.4.0/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
Traceback (most recent call last):
11: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
10: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:44:in `run'
 9: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `do_configuration'
 8: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `new'
 7: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
 6: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
 5: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:684:in `load_yaml'
 4: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 3: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 2: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
 1: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.6/psych.so (LoadError)
22: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
21: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:44:in `run'
20: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `do_configuration'
19: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:79:in `new'
18: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
17: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:346:in `load_file'
16: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:684:in `load_yaml'
15: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
14: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
13: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/2.6.0/psych.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
12: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
11: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:123:in `rescue in require'
10: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:213:in `try_activate'
 9: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find_by_path'
 8: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `find'
 7: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1036:in `each'
 6: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1037:in `block in find_by_path'
 5: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:39:in `compatible?'
 4: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:7:in `bundler_version'
 3: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:22:in `bundler_version_with_reason'
 2: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:68:in `lockfile_version'
 1: from /Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `lockfile_contents'
/Users/waiyanhein/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)
```

I tried to uninstall cocoapod, "sudo gem uninstall cocoapods" as well. It is not even allowing me to run the pod uninstall command. I am getting the same error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed rvm manually, uninstall it and then try to install cocoapods. it worked for me.